# Не загружает картинку из Ip камеры

Tags: c++, opencv

Я делаю программу распознавания автомобильных номеров с IP камер на основе iANPR SDK, OpenCV и Windows Forms. В качестве IP камеры, я подключаю телефон, и на нем приложений IP Web Cam. Телефон пишет что 1 пользователь подключен, и этот пользователь это моя программа. Но проблема в том, что не выводится изображение и конечно не может распознать номера. Есть прикрепленный скриншот. IP адрес камеры задаю в коде, не в интерфейсе программы. Может кто подсказать в чем проблема?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "camera.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "include\iANPR.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Form1.h"
#include <time.h> 

#define WIDTHBYTES(bits) (((bits) + 31) / 32 * 4)

CvCapture* capture;
bool stop;
HBITMAP Bitmap = NULL;
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

// Äëÿ ðàñïîçíàâàíèÿ íîìåðîâ
int all = 100;
CvRect Rects[100];              
char** res;
char outbuf[256];

HBITMAP CreateRGBBitmap(IplImage* _Grab )
{
    char *App;
    LPBITMAPINFO lpbi = new BITMAPINFO;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biWidth = _Grab->width;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biHeight =_Grab->height;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = WIDTHBYTES((DWORD)_Grab->width * 8) * _Grab->height;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    void* pBits;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection( NULL,lpbi,DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void **)&pBits,NULL,0 );
    delete lpbi;
    if ( hBitmap ) App=(char*)pBits;
    long int length=0;
    if(_Grab->nChannels==1) // Ñåðîå èëè áèíàðíîå
    {
           length = _Grab->width*(_Grab->height);
           for (int i=0;i<_Grab->height;i++)
           {
                   for (int j=0;j<_Grab->width;j++)
                   {
                           App[_Grab->width*3*(_Grab->height-i-1)+j*3]=_Grab->imageData[_Grab->width*(i)+j];
                           App[_Grab->width*3*(_Grab->height-i-1)+j*3+1]=_Grab->imageData[_Grab->width*(i)+j];
                           App[_Grab->width*3*(_Grab->height-i-1)+j*3+2]=_Grab->imageData[_Grab->width*(i)+j];
                   }
           }
    }
    if(_Grab->nChannels==3) // Öâåòíîå
    {
           for (int i=0;i<_Grab->height;i++)
           {
                   // Êîïèðóåì ïàìÿòü
                   memcpy(App+_Grab->width*3*(_Grab->height-i-1),_Grab->imageData+_Grab->width*3*i,_Grab->width*3);           
           }
    }   
    return hBitmap;
}

DWORD WINAPI ImageProcess(LPVOID)
{
    ANPR_OPTIONS a;     
    a.Detect_Mode = ANPR_DETECTCOMPLEXMODE;
    a.min_plate_size = 500;
    a.max_plate_size = 25000;
    a.max_text_size = 20;       
    a.type_number = ANPR_RUSSIAN_BASE2;             
    a.flags = 0;

    CvSize Size = cvSize( 320, 240 );
    IplImage* small_image = cvCreateImage( Size, 8, 3 );
    IplImage* object = 0;

    char mem[100][20];
    int all_mem = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        IplImage* frame = 0;    
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture );
        if( !frame )
            break;      
        if (!object)
        {
            object = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 1);         
            cvZero( object );
            object->origin = frame->origin;             
        }
        cvCvtColor( frame, object, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        cvSaveImage( "test.jpg", object );      
        all = 100;

        int i1;
        __try
        {
            i1 = anprPlate( object, a, &all, Rects, res ); 
        }
        __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
        {
            ExitProcess( 1 );
        }

        int number = 0;
        if ( i1 == 0 )
        {                       
            for(int j = 0; j < all; j++ )               
            {               
                if ( strlen( res[j] ) >= 8 )
                {
                    int k =0;
                    for( int j1 = 0; j1 < all_mem; j1++ )
                        if ( strcmp( res[j], mem[j1]) == 0 ) k = 1; // Åñëè íåñêîëüêî ðàç ïîäðÿä îäèí íîìåð, òî ñ÷èòàåòñÿ ðàñïîçíàí ïðàâèëüíî
                    if ( k == 0 ) continue;     
                    cvRectangle( frame,cvPoint( Rects[j].x, Rects[j].y),cvPoint(Rects[j].x+Rects[j].width,
                        Rects[j].y+Rects[j].height), CV_RGB(255,255,0), 2);

                    CvFont font;
                    float aa=0.001f*frame->width;
                    cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, aa,
                                    aa,0,1, 8 ); 
                    CvPoint pp2,pp1;
                    pp2.x=Rects[j].x;
                    pp2.y=Rects[j].y;
                    pp1.x=Rects[j].x+1;
                    pp1.y=Rects[j].y+1;
                    cvPutText( frame, res[j], pp1, &font, CV_RGB(0,0,0) );
                    cvPutText( frame, res[j], pp2, &font, CV_RGB(0,255,0) );
                    if ( j == 0 )
                    {
                        // Äëÿ ïðîñòîòû ñ÷èòàåì, ÷òî â êàäðå ìîæåò áûòü òîëüêî îäèí íîìåð
                        number = 1;
                    }

                }           
            }
            // Êîïèðîâàíèå â ïàìÿòü
            for(int j = 0; j < all; j++ )               
            {
                for( i1 = 0; i1 < strlen( res[j] ); i1++ )
                    if ( res[j][i1] == '?' ) {
                        i1 = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                if ( i1 == -1 ) continue;
                if ( strlen( res[j] ) >= 8 )
                {
                    strcpy( mem[j], res[j] );
                }
            }
            all_mem = all;
        }       

        cvResize( frame, small_image );

EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
        // Òåêóùåå âðåìÿ
        if ( number == 1 )
        {
            time_t rawtime; 
            struct tm * timeinfo; 
            time ( &rawtime ); 
            timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime ); 

            sprintf( outbuf,"Time and data: %s - Number: %s\n", asctime (timeinfo), res[0] ); 
        }
        else outbuf[0] = 0;

        if ( Bitmap != NULL ) DeleteObject(Bitmap);     
        Bitmap = CreateRGBBitmap(frame);    
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);      
        Sleep( 4000 ); // íåáîëüøàÿ çàäåðæêà ïåðåä ñëåäóþùèì êàäðîì
        if ( stop ) break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvReleaseImage( &small_image );
    cvReleaseImage( &object );
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);

    for(int j=0;j<100;j++) delete [] res[j];
    delete [] res;

    return 0;
}

int Start( char* IP, char* Login, char* Password  )
{
    char buf[256];

    sprintf( buf, "http://192.168.60.102:8080/video");  
    //sprintf( buf, "http://192.168.60.102:8080/shot.jpg"); 
    capture = cvCaptureFromFile( buf );
    if ( capture == NULL ) return 1;

    // Ñîçäàòü ïîòîê äëÿ âûâîäà âèäåî
    DWORD lpT;
    stop = false;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    res = new char*[all];
    for(int j=0;j<all;j++) res[j] = new char[20];
    CreateThread( NULL,0,ImageProcess,NULL,0,&lpT); 
    return 0;
}

void Stop()
{
    stop = true;
}

HBITMAP LoadImage_()
{
    return Bitmap;
}

CRITICAL_SECTION* Section_()
{
    return &cs;
}

void GetResult( char* dst )
{
    strcpy_s( dst, 256, outbuf );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]